# Interval of definition of $\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{1-y^2}$ for $y=\sin{x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

For the ODE 
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{1-y^2},
$$
why isn't the interval of definition $(-\infty,\infty)$ for the explicit solution $y=\sin{x}$?

I was taught that a solution for a first-order ODE must be differentiable with at least one continuous derivative on the interval of definition. I believe this solution adheres to this definition on the interval $(-\infty,\infty)$, yet this statement from part of a problem in my text says otherwise. What am I missing here?

Comment: Note: The right hand side is always positive...

Comment: i would say nonnegative